# How to sign-out with SFAuthenticationSession

Tags: ios, swift, oauth, alamofire, aswebauthenticationsession

I use `SFAuthenticationSession` to sign in with SSO to `login.microsoftonline.com`. It works completely fine but there is an issue with logging out. `SFAuthenticationSession` doesn't provide a way to clear cookies. Therefore when I call `SFAuthenticationSession.start()` again I get previous callback url with authentication token instead of allowing a user to provide new credentials.

As a workaround I call `login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/logout` with `SFAuthenticationSession.start()`. It works but the UX experience is worse than terrible.

Is there really no other way to clear cookies with `SFAuthenticationSession`? Session isn't shared with Safari so opening a webview woudln't work neither.

Would `ASWebAuthenticationSession` instead of `SFAuthenticationSession` allow clearing cookies somehow?

I know that quite similar questions have been already asked on SO but maybe there is some update on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to make logout is call **login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/logout** or if you want to use sso between your applications you can use WKWebView, but if you want use sso between Safari and your app the only way is ASWebAuthenticationSession or SFAuthenticationSession. ASWebAuthenticationSession is same as SFAuthenticationSession but they add permission alert view and when you need logout, user will see alert view with question: Do you want to sign in? Hope Apple will fix it